# how to write to storage google cloud with pyspark writestream?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, spark-streaming

I tried to write to GCP storage from pyspark stream.
This is the code:

```
df_test\
.writeStream.format("parquet")\
.option("path","gs://{my_bucketname}/test")\
.option("checkpointLocation", "gs://{my_checkpointBucket}/checkpoint")\
.start()\
.awaitTermination()
```

but I got this error:

```
20/11/15 16:37:59 WARN CheckpointFileManager: Could not use FileContext API 
for managing Structured Streaming checkpoint files at gs://name- 
bucket/test/_spark_metadata
 .Using FileSystem API instead for managing log files. If the implementation 
 of FileSystem.rename() is not atomic, then the correctness and fault- 
 tolerance ofyour Structured Streaming is not guaranteed.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "testgcp.py", line 40, in <module>
 .option("checkpointLocation", "gs://check_point_bucket/checkpoint")\
 File "/home/naya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/pyspark/sql/streaming.py", line 1105, in start
 return self._sq(self._jwrite.start())
 File "/home/naya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", 
 line 1257, in __call__
 answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
 File "/home/naya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", 
 line 63, in deco
 return f(*a, **kw)
 File "/home/naya/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", 
 line 328, in get_return_value
 format(target_id, ".", name), value)
 py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o55.start.
 : java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: gs
```

what should be the right syntax?

Comment: You lack in your spark install the necessary gcs connector so the 'gs' scheme is unknown you should install the gcs-connector to your spark app before

Answer (score 0):

As per this [documentation](https://medium.com/@junjiejiang94/3-easy-step-to-use-google-storage-with-pyspark-fd053d1bde9). It seems that first you need to set the spark.conf with the proper authentication.

```html
spark.conf.set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable", "true")
spark.conf.set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.email", "Your_service_email")
spark.conf.set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.keyfile", "path/to/your/files")
```

Then you can access the file in your bucket using the read function.

```html
df = spark.read.option("header",True).csv("gs://bucket_name/path_to_your_file.csv")
df.show()
```